# SharePoint list- Export to excel error in SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I have a SharePoint(2007) list which has around 3500 rows each with aroudn 40 fields.

We have a load balancing environment for our SharePoint portal, where we have 2 servers for eg

Server A and Server B. The both servers have same type of configurations.

When I do Export to Excel in SharePoint list, when the portal is pointing to Server A, I get the below error.

**"An operation that uses the database driver could not be completed. If the driver is a Microsoft driver, make sure the driver file isn't damaged, and it it is, reinstall the driver by reinstalling Microsoft Query."**

But when I point to the other server B, the error is not coming and the data is exported to excel.

Anyhelp why I am not able to perform Export to Excel in the server A.

Thanks in Advance

Padma

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing,

Increase number of "List View Threshold" in Web application General setting.
Central Admin –> Manage Web Applications –> Select your web app & click –> General Settings > Resource Throttling.

I changed the value to 10000. The Excel works perfectly.

Thanks again for your support & Have a nice day,
Hai

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved. Root cause is the piece of code I am accessing the logfile do not included RuWithElevatedPrivileges. So, when I addde this code while opening the config file, the issue is resolved.